# Use measurement protocol to create transaction/item for a specific date

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am using the following URL to generate an item for the transaction.

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=someID&cid=someID&ti=126540&ta=Another%20type&tr=400.00&tt=0&ea=Purchase&pa=purchase&ec=Enhanced%20Ecommerce&ts=0&cu=UAH&t=event&pr1id=cha803478-WTC%2FNBK&pr1nm=foo%202PP%20crew%20socks&pr1ca=foo&pr1pr=199.00&pr1br=foo&pr1qt=1
```

After a few days I will need to change it, because any data in it will be not correct. Is there a way to specify date on this URL so that the modification of the transaction was the day it was created?

Answer (score 0):

No. While there is the [queue time parameter that allows for a few hours offset](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) there is not way to specify a date in a hit (that would force Google to reprocess a lot of data to integrate hits for previous dates in the reports).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification